# pdfinfo optimized

Tags: pdf, compression

What means optimized in the info pdfinfo shows?

```
pdfinfo file.pdf 
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          642
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      1004.16 x 658.56 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      12841384 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

Maybe it indicates if the pdf is compressed or not, but I have shrunk the original size of the pdf from 77 MB to 12.8 MB...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, [according to the source code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/blob/master/utils/pdfinfo.cc#L835) *Optimized* means *linearized*.

[What are linearized PDF files?](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51711_01/TSG/FAQ/What%20are%20linearized%20PDF%20files_.html)

> A linearized PDF file is a special format of a PDF file that makes
> viewing faster over the Internet. Linearized PDF files contains
> information that allow a byte-streaming server to download the PDF
> file one page at a time. If byte-streaming is disabled on the server
> or if the PDF file is not linearized, the entire PDF file must be
> downloaded before it can be viewed. All supported versions of IDS
> produce linearized PDF files.

Comment: Great answer.  This link will likely bit rot over time but the relevant line is:

     printf("Optimized: %s\n", doc->isLinearized() ? "yes" : "no");

Here:  https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/blob/master/utils/pdfinfo.cc#L908